# Scrapy Link extractor doesn't get past second link in depth

Tags: python, scrapy

Link extractor doesn't get links past the second link in deep.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "test"
    link_extractor = LinkExtractor()
    

    def parse(self, response):

        unique_links = []

        for link in self.link_extractor.extract_links(response):
            unique_links.append(link)

        print(unique_links)

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl('test', start_urls=['https://www.telusinternational.com/'])
process.start(stop_after_crawl=False)
```

For example, unique_links will get https://www.telusinternational.com/about/our-team but not https://www.telusinternational.com/about/our-team/jeff-puritt?INTCMP=ti_our-team_card_jeff-puritt_leadership-team

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make requests for each of the links you want the Spider to follow to the next page.

```
    def parse(self, response):
        unique_links = []
        for link in self.link_extractor.extract_links(response):
            unique_links.append(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(link.url)
        print(unique_links)
```

Comment: I get exactly the same result. Anyway, LinkExtractor() wasn't supposed to extract all the links from the response?

Comment: @alex65535  What is it you think the link extractor does?